# Pass classname to material ui date-picker dialog

Tags: reactjs, materialize

Is there a way to pass classname to matererial-ui datepicker's dialog.

http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/date-picker

Material-ui's datepicker accepts `classname` as a prop. But, this gets applied to the `text-field` upon which we want to trigger the `date-dialog`.

I want to pass a `class attribute` to the date-popup itself. Something like:
    `dialogClassName`

The need is I want to access if the click was done somewhere inside the date-dialog and manage some other part of my code based on that. I can't figure out how to make the date-dialog accept a `classname`.

This issue was a bit boosting,https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/5329 but passing a `dialogClassName` doesn't get applied.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find out any solution?

Comment: Hi @ArchanaSharma. there was no way you could pass the class name. I ended up using a separate date-picker.

Answer (score 3):

There is a solution which I came across by going through the DatePicker Code. You can pass the following props to the DatePicker

```
<DatePicker>
    PopperProps={{
                  className: classes.desktopView,
                }}
    DialogProps={{
                  className: classes.mobileView,
                }}
</DatePicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you cannot do that without modifying the DatePicket component ( at least not without some wild hacks).

If you really need this functionality you can fork material-ui repository, make the changes and submit a pull request. Or, in you project, create a local DatePicker component and do the changes there, but this approach requires you to update your version in case material-ui's version is updated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution as of yet. However there is a workaround to pass a css class name to popup/dialog container. 
Pass an img tag for rightArrowIcon props of datepicker with onload function to call its parent and inject css class.

```
<DatePicker
   disableToolbar={true}
   variant="inline"  
   inputVariant="outlined"  
   rightArrowIcon={<img src="/images/chevron-right_1.svg" id="datepicker-arrow-right" onLoad={injectTheme}/>}
   leftArrowIcon={<img src="/images/chevron-right_1.svg" style={{transform:"rotate(180deg)"}}/>}    
....
....
....
/>

const injectTheme=()=>{
let node = document.getElementById("datepicker-arrow-right").parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentElement;
    node.classList.add("Css-Class-Name"); 
}
```